# Understanding Kafka's Producer Error Rate Metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, producer

https://kafka.apache.org/24/generated/producer_metrics.html notes:

`record-error-rate`: The average per-second number of record sends that resulted in errors

`record-error-total`: The total number of record sends that resulted in errors

Publishing to Kafka involves two steps:

1. write the message to the buffer
2. ACK from broker that the message was accepted

Do the above error metrics apply to step 1 or 2?